# Error when mixing mixed functions in vitis HLS

Tags: vivado-hls, vitis, xilinx-vitis

I have the below code in vitis hls, the STREAM is powered by the AXI interface ports that are supplied to the function.

```
func1(){
    static hls::stream<int> buffer("buffer1");
    #pragma HLS STREAM variable=buffer depth=100
    #pragma HLS DATAFLOW
    //Algorithm
}
    
    
func2(){
    static hls::stream<int> buffer2("buffer2");
    #pragma HLS STREAM variable=buffer2 depth=100
    #pragma HLS DATAFLOW
    //Algorithm
}

acc(int type){
 //AXI interface
 if(type){
    func1();
 }else{
    func2();
 }
}
```

Also, I have a testbench to call the acc function with both types.
The problem I have is that if I run only one of the functions then the C/RTL COSIMULATION works correctly, but if I want to do with both, my test fails and the final RTL.

Do you have any idea what is happens, and how can I solve it?